# Why is rudeness tolerated here?

Tags: discussion

I asked (in a standard, neutral way) a factual question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/113104/8345) and got an  answer whose tone I disapproved of.
I said so in a comment and the answerer wrote back [two comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/113110/8345) in quite rude language (and completely deforming the meaning of what I said. He also makes irrelevant remarks on defenders of idiocy getting elected to congress ).
He accuses me of having a serious problem, more than a writing problem, promulgating, propagating, or populating stupidities, being high-toned ...
Of course I stopped communicating with him, but I want to ask if such behaviour is tolerated here. It would be most unfortunate if it were.
(Let me insist that I am in no way discussing the content of the answer, which it is of course perfectly legitimate for the answerer to defend)

**Edit**
Another user, @Ben, has now removed two contentious adjectives from the answer, explaining in his edit that  "rudeness is not tolerated here". Nice to read that: thanks, Ben!

Comment: Rudeness is disliked but intolerance of it takes work. Also, from the single instance, it has nothing to do with you, but all to do with the rude commenter. Note that one can always -flag- (but abuse of that can be controlled also).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry you have had an unpleasant interaction here. I will look into that comment chain and see if I can help.

Naturally, rudeness is not tolerated here. Pointing out a problem on Meta is one way to address the issue. You can also flag any comment you think is rude and mark it as such. That way, it brings it to the attention of the mod team.

Comment: Thank you very much, KitFox: I was hoping for an answer along these lines and am very glad you provided it. And I would hope that your being a moderator endows this answer with an official status.

Comment: @Georges I purged most of the comments. There was some useful information there, but I felt that salvaging that would just have made the situation worse. If there's anything else that concerns you, you can post here, or use a custom flag to let us know.

Comment: I can only renew my thanks to you, KitFox. I quite agree that there was some quite interesting information there: it is a pity that it was counter-productively lost because of the  tone of some comments.